# jQuery hover multiple ID's from php generated DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I'm having some troubles with a jQuery script.

I get my div's generated with PHP based on data from SQL.

```
echo "<div class='order' id='a$i' runat='server' draggable='true' >";
```

On mouseover it shows a different div also generated from PHP and SQL.

```
echo "<div class='position' id='b$i2' runat='server' draggable='true'>";
```

Then i have a jQuery script that has the hover function for the second div.
Every div get's it's ID from php. Menu div's get a1, a2, a3.... and hover div's get b1, b2, b3....

```
$(function() {

              var moveLeft = 20;
              var moveDown = 10;
              var r = 1;


              $('div#a'+r).hover(function(e) {


                $('div#b'+r).show();

              }, function() {
                $('div#b'+r).hide();

              });

              $('div#a'+r).mousemove(function(e) {
                $("div#b"+r).css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);

              });

            });
```

The code works for the first div, or the div i specify with the r variable.
I'm having troubles with code working for all the ID's on the page. They get generated based on SQL data.

https://postimg.org/image/ooqnfkx3n/

Is there a way to do this using LOOP function? Or getting the ID from generated div's?

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Yes there's a way to loop through them but it's not going to be very simple. I would suggest, if possible, to modify the PHP so it adds a specific class to those divs and use that to loop through them easily. It will make your life much easier and your code less error prone.

Comment: My div's already have classes, when i hover on ORDER class div it should show POSITION class div. They look like this:
https://postimg.org/image/ooqnfkx3n/

Answer (score 0):

Use `starts with` selector

```
$("div[id^='a']").hover(function(event) {
    //Do your thing
}
```

Documentation: [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/#post-51)

Comment: It just shows the same div on all.

I need it to show b1 on a1, b2 on a2, b3 on a3....

Comment: You need to use this code after those dynamic `div` elements have been appended.

Comment: I need to specify ID from first div's to show the corresponding ID div.

Answer (score 0):

How about you add the hover event on class instead of div but add logic based on div.

```
$(".theclassofA").hover(function(event) {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var temp_rel = //then get the integer 'r' from this id
var temp_id = "b"+temp_rel;
//use this temp_id to show/hide your elements
}
```

Comment: I have classes already specified, is there a way to just add the logic to r variable?

Comment: what do you mean by "logic to r variable?"
If you have some good unique id (NOT a1) which wont hurt your html page, then you can go with the philantrovert's answer below, that would do.

Other than that you can associate event to class and then get the id, r from it and do your stuff. Makes sense ?

Comment: All i need is to change the r variable in the script for every div i have generated. Everything else works...If i copy the same script and just change the r value (1,2,3,4,5...) it works.

Comment: Adding for loop for binding is not really good approach, just try this and tweak a bit to suit your implementation.

`
$(".order").hover(function(event) {
   var order_id = $(this).attr('id');
   var position_id = "b"+order_id .replace('a','');

   //tweak your code
   $('div#'+order_id ).hover(function(e) {
                $('div#'+position_id).show();

              }, function() {
                $('div#'+position_id).hide();
              });
});
`